# Delete text after specific character

Tags: string, delphi

I have the text inside TEdit box:
'955-986, total = 32'

How would I delete all text after the comma, so it will only left '955-986'

I tried to limit the TEdit Length, but it's not working as I wanted it to be.

Comment: Did you do some research, just a little bit? `Delete(S, Pos(',', S), MaxInt)`.

Comment: Or e.g. `var S: string; begin S := Edit1.Text; Edit1.Text := Copy(S, 1, Pos(',', S) - 1); end;`

Comment: TLama's immutable variation fits even better.

Comment: Free Consulting: It's working anyway.  @TLama this is exactly. Thank you!

Comment: @FreeConsulting I think FP-like immutable approach would rather be StringSplit over comma's :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The, immutability is valuable here because `.Text` is a property and won't fit as `var` parameter. Using a temporary variable unlock mutability and you can delegate whole job to `Delete` because it uses kinda opposite approach than `Copy`/`SetLength`. Gonna post it.

Comment: @FreeConsulting to me the difference here is not [im]mutability but rather "property is not variable". Even the TLama's code there uses temporary `S` (though it can easily do without it)

Comment: @Arioch'The, well, property is immutable, so we cannot solve a simple OP's problem with correspondingly simple one-liner. Take a look at my solution, it exploits checking of params done by `Delete`, so no branching is necessary.

Comment: @freeconsulting hmm,  I think anything that you can assign values to (more than once) is mutable by definition. It is matter of taste,  but I think that my answer is better for being more explicit ( checking is really exploited there, and not giving performance benefits in return) and avoiding to call a complex GDI - involving setter when does not have too. While your code also deals with no-comma case I think w/o a comment it is harder to realize when quick reading

Comment: @Arioch'The, it is setter's job to not change object state when assigned same value. For explanation I linked a documentation

Comment: @FreeConsulting not trying to do redundant things is better than heuristics trying to detect it and skip after the fact. Attempt to skip resizing when size not changed, for example, lead to TListView bug with auto-size columns and scroll-bars

Comment: @Arioch'The, is there similar bug in TEdit.Text setter?

Comment: @FreeConsulting There is no bug in any setter, there is a fragile assumption about the setter doing its work fully and always without aggressive optimizations. Your code uses fragile "implementation details" assumption about speed instead of outright expression what is intended. All the hacks based in "implementation details" are fragile and harder to read (maintain and refactor). Sometimes that is the price to pay for some benefit. But here I see the only benefit of code density: removing one "if" statement to save about dozen bytes of RAM. I don't like this exchange personally,  YMMV

Comment: @Arioch'The, no, it is neither "fragile", nor "a hack". It is based upon intended and documented behaviour of `Delete`. Please visit a doc link.

Comment: @freeconsulting Last few messages we talked about skipping or invoking redundant win GDI calls inside TEdit.SetText in regards of no-comma case. Delete(x,0,y) is documented, it just is harder to read. That is employing (abusing In your own words) a sly trick in a place where that does not benefit other than "I am smart" show off. YMMV

Comment: @Arioch'The, I never sayd what I am "abusing". I am **exploiting** behaviours (which in no way are hidden for ones who read linked doc) of `Delete` and delegating work to this routine. There is nothing "sly" or too "smart" behind, just elimination of unneeded code. You didnt make your point, my solution will work as long as contract remains unchanged.

Comment: @freeconsulting hmm,  I remember I saw "[ab]using" wording. Perhaps it was in different place or refined later. Okay with "exploiting" - in my book that is about being sly as well. And sometimes that is worth. But not always. You tell you linked documentation,  I suggested to put comments into the code. That is all about the same. My dumb code is explicit. You don't have to stop to understand it's behaviour in no-comma case. In you case one has to make stop in Reading and think "what is special case when param=not-found?"

Comment: ... Reading and think "what is special case when param=not-found?" or even read docwiki. It makes reading the program code slower. Not by much but still. And for - in this particular case - no benefit. Again,  YMMV, but my personal gut feeling suggests this

Comment: @Arioch'The, even making code **too explicit** does not save you from the too lazy reader who **personally** have a little idea how `Pos` or `SetLength` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if there'd be no comma? full non-cut string or empty string ?

Below is your idea of limiting string length, but only applied if at least one comma was found.

```
var 
    tmpStr:string;
    commaPosition:integer; 
begin
  tmpStr := Edit1.Text;
  commaPosition := pos(',',tmpStr);
  if commaPosition > 0 then begin
     SetLength(tmpStr, commaPosition - 1);
     Edit1.Text := tmpStr;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This way is hard for me to read. `Copy` or `Delete` are self-explanatory while this is not. [not voting in this thread]

Comment: @TLama funny, for me it is the opposite. And the topicstarter seems to share my preferences ("how to limit the length") on what is easier to grasp. `Copy` has one more parameter, and `Delete` is focused on a garbage rather than on the data we really need. But it is personal of course. However that is not the main benefit of my answer, but acknowledging "no comma" case possible. PS. I also rarely vote in threads where I participate :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use this code:

```
var 
    tmpStr:string;
    commaPosition:integer; 
begin
  tmpStr := Edit1.Text;
  commaPosition := pos(',',tmpStr);
  tmpStr := copy(tmpStr,1,commaPosition-1);
  Edit1.Text := tmpStr;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Delphi-Programmer (any more). However, I guess you get the String from the Text-Property of your TEdit-Box object, search for the first occurrence of `,` and get the index thereof and replace the Text contained in your TEdit-Box by the substring from the beginning of the current string to the found index.

```
edit.Text := Copy(edit.Text, 1, Pos(',', edit.Text)-1);
```

Sources:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Copy
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i want. As TLama direction. Thank you for the brief.

Answer (score 2):

TEdit.Text is a property and cannot be passed as `var` parameter. But once you introduce temporary variable, you can delegate checking of character index returned from `Pos` to [`Delete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Delete) and it will handle all of cases.

```
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := Edit1.Text;  // try '955-986, total = 32' and '955-986; total = 32'
  Delete(S, Pos(',', S), MaxInt);
  Edit1.Text := S;
end;
```