# Delete text before specific character in delphi

Tags: delphi

Help
I have many strings, I want to keep string after symbol **/**,  they are like:
63728/4817847 become **4817847** ,
345/7895 become **7895** ,
1289/98721 become **98721** ,
1876789/987 become **987** .
I still have not found a way, because the number of strings to be stored or to be deleted is changing every time.
Thanks.

Comment: where is your code? this is not a solve me my problem page! You do no efforts to solve yourself the problem.

Comment: thanks, mr.bitman.. I'm stil tryng my code,  my key is using this,  s_thgput1 := StringReplace(s_thgput1,'/','',[rfIgnoreCase, rfReplaceAll]); but still didnt find the other way coz I am in working while studying.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858501/delete-text-after-specific-character?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Not the same. The linked post removes the text at the end of the string following the comma delimiter; this poster wants to remove the first portion of the string and delimiter.

Comment: @KenWhite: I saw that. But there are "some" similarities between these tasks. For example, one of the answers to that Q suggests using `Pos` and `Copy`, which would work equally well in this case too. Of course, you need to actually understand the A (maybe even read the docs!) in order to make the necessary changes, but that is quite healthy in any way. (Or were you joking? For the record, I didn't downvote your A.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I didn't think you downvoted. I don't know why someone did - it's a perfectly fine answer that offers two appropriate solutions to the OP's problem. I was just pointing out the differences between the two posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using a combination of `Pos` and `Copy`.

```
  Source := '1876789/987';
  // Find position of `/` in the string
  Index := Pos('/', Source);
  if Index > 0 then
    // Extract portion of string following the '/' (the + 1) to the end
    Source := Copy(Source, Index + 1, Length(Source));
```

As SilverWarior pointed out in a comment, you could also use `System.Delete`.

```
Source := '1876789/987';
System.Delete(Source, 1, Pos('/', Source));
```

Comment: Instead of [Copy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Copy) you could also make use of [Delete](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Delete) which allows you to remove part of existing string without the need to copy it to a new string first.

Comment: @SilverWarior: That's another option. You could also use a regular expression, if you wanted to add tons of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Well the nice thing about [Delete[(http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Delete) is that you can do all that you have done with single line of code `Delete(Source,1,Pos('/', Source));` and you don't need any additional string or integer variables.

Comment: @SilverWarior: I added (with attribution) an example of using  Delete as well, so the user has the option. I'm not going to do the regex version, because I wouldn't use one for this simple task. :-)

Comment: I agree with you. Using RegEx for such a simple task is a total overkill.

Comment: @SilverWarior: If you want to write an answer instead with the Delete code, I'll delete mine. Mine was overly cautious, based on my feeling that the OP is a new coder. Your solution is much cleaner, though.

Comment: what a great way from @ SilverWarior and Ken White.. all are work.. thanks so much..

Comment: The reason why I didn't write an answer with the use of Delete function but comment instead is that I liked the fact that your answer was well commented and showed in detail of how this can be done manually.

Comment: @SilverWarior "Delete which allows you to remove part of existing string without the need to copy it to a new string first" if we're being accurate, this is only true for strings having a reference count of 1. For refCount of 2+, copy would perform better. In most situations, I'd expect Copy to have a better average case than delete.